# How to recover a message with shared modulus for textbook RSA

Tags: rsa

Same message sent to two users encrypted with textbook RSA, known $n$, $e_1$, $e_2$, $c_1$, $c_2$. Show how the attacker can recover the message.

### Problem statement

> Consider an RSA system with $n=143$, $e_1=7$ and $e_2=17$. Suppose the same message $m$ was sent to the two users above and the attacker observed the ciphertext $c_1 =42$ and $c_2 =9$. Show how the attacker can recover the message.

### Official solution

> Use Extended Euclidian algorithm to find $a$ and $b$ such that
> $a\,e_1 + b\,e_2 = 1$. Then we obtain $m$ as ${c_1}^a + {c_2}^b \bmod n$ thus $m=3$

### My attempt at solving the problem

Having read [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1614/rsa-cracking-the-same-message-is-sent-to-two-different-people-problem/1616#1616) and watched [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OrVWAYonFIU), I did the following, but I get the wrong answer:

Using the Extended Euclidean algorithm I get $a = 5$ and $b = -2$ for  $a\,e_2 + b\,e_1 = 1$. (According to the comment section of the YouTube video, $a$ from the video, let's call it alpha, needs to be greater than or equal to $b$ from the video, let's call it beta; alpha = $e_2$ and beta = $e_1$.)

Then
$$\begin{align}
m &= ({c_2}^a + {c_1}^b) \bmod n\\
i &= {c_1}^{-1} \bmod n\\
m &= ( {c_2}^a i^{-b} ) \bmod n\\ 
i &= 42^{-1} \bmod 143\\
42i &= 1 \bmod 143\\
i &= (1+143\times \nu)/42\\
\nu &= 37\implies i = 126\\
m &= ({c_2}^5 + i^2) \bmod 143\\
m &= (9^5 + 126^2) \bmod 143\\
m &= 136 \neq 3
\end{align}$$

Could someone please help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

Edit:
Here's my work (in a corrected way), and in a way that won't expire (since the message where I showed my work will eventually expire), in case it helps someone else:
For 1 to 3 of the "Hint to derive the correct equation" part:
To prove that m^1 mod n = m, we know that since m < n and anything less than than the divisor yields the dividend in a modulo expression.

Then, using the properties you mentioned ( the x^(u+v) and x^(uv) stuff from here: https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/81829/21 ), with the constraints described in (4) from here ( [Definition of $x^u \bmod k$](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/81873/definition-of-xu-bmod-k/81882#81882) ), I get
m = m^1 mod n

m = m^(a e_1 + b e_2) mod n

m = [m^(a e_1) mod n] ] m^(b e_2) mod n] mod n

m = ({[m^(e_1) mod n]}^a) mod n ({[m^(e_2) mod n]}^b) mod n

m = ({C_1}^a) mod n ({C_2}^b) mod n

m = {(C_1^a) mod n (C_2^b) mod n} mod n

m = (C_1^a · C_2^b) mod n.

From the constraints described in (4), we know that it must be the case that gcd(C_2,n) = 1 (which can be seen in the (4) from the case where u < 0, k > 1 and gcd(x,k) = 1, assuming x = C_2 and u = b < 0) for the modular inverse labelled as i, here ( [RSA cracking: The same message is sent to two different people problem](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1614/rsa-cracking-the-same-message-is-sent-to-two-different-people-problem/1616#1616) ), to be defined, and therefore for the whole expression for the (plaintext) message m to be defined (unless C_1^a * C_2^b yields an integer, even if a < 0 or b < 0).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what I am doing wrong?

Accepting as fact a recipe with an equation, rather than deriving it.

Illustration: « Then we obtain $m$ as ${c_1}^a + {c_2}^b \bmod n$ » is stated rather than derived. And wrong.

As an aside the question reverses $a$ and $b$ (or is it $c_1$ and $c_2$, or $e_1$ and $e_2$): they are correct per the official solution which asks $a\,e_1 + b\,e_2 = 1$, but the calculation then made assumes and states $a\,e_2 + b\,e_1 = 1$.

Hint to derive the correct equation:

1. Prove that $m^1\bmod n=m$, by combining the definition¹ of raising to an integer exponent, the assumed range of $m$ in textbook RSA, and the definition² of the $\bmod$ operator.
2. In this equation, substitute $1$ with $a\,e_1 + b\,e_2$ where $a$ and $b$ are the Bezout coefficients such that $a\,e_1 + b\,e_2=1$.
3. Properly use properties³ of modular exponentiation. In cryptanalysis it's OK to assume plausible preconditions when that's necessary, but it remains good to verify them (or the result derived) in the end.

---

Suggestion: apply this technique with a slightly larger $n=14835196795348830319$, $(e_1,e_2)=(3,5)$, and $(c_1,c_2)=(14562201346830272020,1832973312396331965)$. As a bonus find the menu by expressing $m$ in hex. The point of these larger numbers is that guessing the Bezout coefficients and inverse is harder, and slightly more computer skills are needed.

More mathematically interesting, for a different method is needed, which would still work if $n$ was too large to factor directly from its value: with the same $(n,e_1,e_2)$ find $m$ for $(c_1,c_2)=(11810011337245959646,2207245693327700143)$.

---

Note: in actual use, RSA encryption

- Does not reuse the same $n$ among several public keys, making this particular attack fail.
- Does not directly encode the message as $m$, but rather adds randomness to the message in order to form $m$. That makes it extremely unlikely that $m$ is reused (it would be enough to allow some other attacks including with different $n$).
- Uses $n$ with several hundred decimal digits in order to resist factorization. $n=143$ can be factored mentally, and the larger $n$ is factored in a small fraction of a second using a computer, which allows to find $m$ by using the normal RSA decryption equation, without needing $c_2$ or $e_2$.

---

Appreciation: taking at face value the statement that the extended Euclidean algorithm was used, the question shows fair skills to *apply* equations and algorithms, despite the inversion of $a$ and $b$. Be assured that the goal of such exercises is *not* learning the equations used. It's to learn to *derive* the necessary equations. That's easier when one gets the hang of it, and more fun. It's more reliable, and thus gets higher marks (which is a valid sub-goal) even when the reasoning is not considered in the notation. As a skill it's more useful, more adaptable, less likely to go obsolete, or unused and forgotten.

---

¹ ² ³ : See [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/81882/555) definition of $x^u\bmod k$ and related typographical conventions, or refer to [a previous version](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/81829/21) of the present answer.

Comment: @Alfred Kaminski : Comments are not for extended discussion. This conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110594/discussion-on-answer-by-fgrieu-how-to-recover-a-message-with-shared-modulus-for), where our exchange now stands. Also note that the present answer was trimmed by making reference to [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/81882/555) definition of $x^u\bmod k$.